# React Nat Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application

Tags: reactjs, firebase, native

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

I get this warning when I try to take some datas from firebase, the app works but I just get a warning, this is my code:

```
 const [MeasuresList, setMeasuresList] = useState()


    useEffect(()=> {
        getData()
    })

    function getData(){
        getMeasures(MeasuresRetrived)
    }

    function MeasuresRetrived(MeasuresList){
        setMeasuresList(MeasuresList)
    }


    return (
        
        <View style={styles.content}>
            <Text title semi center>{route.params.muscle}</Text>
            <View style={{height: 20 }}/>
                     <FlatList style={styles.flatList}
                        data = {MeasuresList}
                        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => 
                        <ExList list={item}/>
                        }
                    />
 
        </View>
```

And this is my getMeasures:

```
export async function getMeasures(measureRetrived){
    var measuresList = []
    var snapshot = await firebase
                            .firestore()
                            .collection("Measures")   
                            .get()
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const measureDoc = doc.data()
        measureDoc.id = doc.id
        measuresList.push(measureDoc)
    })
    measureRetrived(measuresList)
}
```

How can I solve?

Comment: You don't have a dependency array with your `useEffect`, you should start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some memory leak, You have to use the `useEffect` hook by giving the dependencies, in this case an empty dependency with `[]` .

```
useEffect(()=> {
    getData()
}, [])
```